# how define computed property in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to add an object which has dynamic property name into an array but I don't know how to define the array

```
class Driver {
    public id: string;
    public name: string;
    constructor(id , name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

let drivers: Driver[];
let driver = new Driver("1111","tom");
drivers.push({[driver.id]:driver})
```

Comment: Not related to the solution: in your constructor: `this.id = name` should be `this.name = name`.

Comment: `let drivers: Array<{[id: string]: Driver}>;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know what the key for those objects will be beforehand, you'll want to use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). So for your example, you would define the type like so:

```
let drivers: {[id: string]: Driver}[];
```